# Error: personal_unlockAccount method not implemented

Tags: ethereum

I'm testing with nethereum(.Net integration library for `Ethereum`) trying to unlock account API on testrpc with following code:

```
var ipcClient = ClientFactory.GetClient();
var web3 = new Web3(ipcClient);

// Unlock the caller's account with the given password
var unlockResult = await web3.Personal.UnlockAccount.SendRequestAsync(publicKey, password, _accountUnlockTime);

        return unlockResult;
```

I have executed `testrpc` on powershell, and have 10 default accounts created by testrpc, and want to unlock on of them.

calling this method i get following exception:

`Error: RPC method personal_unlockAccount not supported.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testrpc does not have the capability to unlock accounts, this is specific of a client like Geth.

Comment: so, i don't need to unlock? just use `web3.Eth.DeployContract` and other functions? also glad to see you here